# Javascript: How to append childs to section element?

Tags: javascript

Assuming that I have the following HTML:

```
<body>
    <section role="main">
    </section>
</body>
```

1) Can I do this?

```
var section = document.getElementsByTagName("section");
```

2) Can I do this?

```
var section = document.querySelector("section[role=main]");
```

3) And finally, how can I append childs to this element? appendChild() doesn't work.

```
var p = document.createElement("p").innerText("A paragraph.");
section.appendChild(p);
```

Comment: it totally depends on your needs and your markup, whether you should use either 1) or 2) ... you can do any of the two..

Comment: Look in the browser's error console. You should see something about `innerText` not being a function.

Comment: When should I use each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either 1 or 2,
Using `getElementsByTagName` -
check out the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/2jzho6hh/3/
this one returns an array of all elements with tag name `section`, so to access the first `section` element you have to use the 0 index on the array. For the second element use 1 index on the array and so on..

Using `querySelector`,
check the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/2jzho6hh/2/
querySelector returns first element matching the selector you have specified as in this case `section[role=main]` which means select the first `section`element with *attribute* *role* and its *value* being *main*

There is also one other method `querySelectorAll` which is, you may think, a union of above two methods. It selects elements on the basis of CSS selector syntax just like `querySelector` does and it returns an array of all elements matching the selector just like the `getElementsByTagName`

Answer (score -1):

Correct code is

```js
var p = document.createElement("p");
 p.innerHTML="A paragraph";
section.appendChild(p);
```

don't add innerHTML  at the time of declaring p.If you do so p will not return child node.Declare p as a node and then add innerhtml to it.